# nodeJS class Import

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi can someone explain me how i cam import my MongoDB request from the constructor to my controller?

Class to export:

```
    class getCampus {
constructor (){
    data.collection('campuses').find({}).toArray(function (err, campus) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({ 'error': 'en error has occured'});
            } else {
                res.send(campus);
            }
        });
    }
}
module.exports = getCampus;
```

where i want to import it

```
app.get('/campuses', (req, res) => {
    // data.collection('campuses').find({}).toArray(function (err, campus) {
    //     if (err) {
    //         res.send({ 'error': 'en error has occured'});
    //     } else {
    //         res.send(campus);
    //     }
    // });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that if let say:

```
 // getCampus.js
 class getCampus {
    // ... your code
 }
 module.exports = getCampus;
```

And then use it like:

```
 const getCampus = require('getCampus'); // <-- Path and name of your file (you can ommit the .js)
 app.get('/campuses', async function(req, res) {
     const campus = await getCampus(); // Added async/await if getCampus is an asynchronous operation
     res.send(campus);
 }
```

However, I would recommend to name your class as your Domain, like so:

```
 // Campus.js
 class Campus {
     constructor(var1, var2, etc) {
        // define whatever is needed to build a campus
     }
     getCampus(id) {
        // Now this is a getter to your campus
     }
     getCampuses() {
     }
 }
```

And then call it like:

```
const Campus = require('Campus');
const campusObj = new Campus;
const arrCampus = campusObj.getCampuses();
```

In this way, your code will be cleaner and easier to maintain. There is a bunch of ways to do this, I would recommend you take a look at [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: thank you for the answer! but i don't know why i have this error message: "TypeError: Class constructor getCampus cannot be invoked without 'new'"